# Can I capture any errors from Debug > Compile with VBA (Excel 2010)?

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code (link below) very useful but **is it possible to suppress compile error msgboxes and also capture the compile errors somehow**?

[Can I compile VBA on workbook open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001620/can-i-compile-vba-on-workbook-open)

For example I am currently reloading common modules in a list of workbooks.  The compile code runs after dynamically reloading all the modules into each file, before moving on to the next file.  I get a series of msgboxes within VBA Editor, I have to click OK for each box, but I can't stop the code at that point.

Ideally, I want to be able to halt (or pause) mid-process and take action within the file to correct the errors, before continuing with the process and updating the modules in the remaining files.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you get msgboxes just press CTRL+Pause to halt the code. This will pop up the typical debug dialog as soon as you close the msgbox. But how are you even able to execute code if there is a compile error?

Comment: Ah, I begin to understand: You are dynamically loading vba modules on runtime, some of them not being compilable. If you try to compile them on runtime anyways you get error messages that cannot be caught by `On Error` statements. If this is what you mean, can you please update the question so it is more clear?

Comment: That sounds like what I'm doing, yes.  Editing now

Comment: No, you can't trap compile errors with code.

Comment: That CTRL+Pause trick worked like a charm, thanks Leviathan!